# How to format integers in Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting, format, numbers

I have the numbers:

```
'115000000000'
'10000000'
'99700000000'
```

I need to make them look like this:

```
'1150,00000000'
'0,10000000'
'997,00000000'
```

or

```
'1150'
'0,1'
'997'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = ['115000000000', '10000000', '99700000000']
nn= [str(  float(float(element)/100000000)   ) for element in n]
```

results in nn to be:

```
['1150.0', '0.1', '997.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
numbers = ['115000000000', '10000000', '99700000000']
for number in numbers:
    number = float(number)/100_000_000  # number seems to be a string? Also _ improves readability
    output = f'{number:.8f}'.replace('.', ',')  # 8 = numbers of decimal digits (decimal number -> float -> f)
```